# Redirect subdomain to directory on a different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, pinnacle-cart

**General Idea**

Is it possible to redirect sub.domain1.com to www.domain2.com/directory

**More Specifics**

I want to redirect a Pinnacle Cart installation from store.pinnaclecart.com to www.domain.com/store but all the cart files will remain on Pinnacle Cart's server @ store.pinnalcecart.com. Is this possible & will it work? I have access to .htaccess on both servers.

**More Specifics EDIT**

 I'd like all the links at sub.domain1.com to read domain2.com/dir apologies if this is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file at `store.pinnaclecart.com`, you'll need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/directory/$1 [L,R]
```

Then in the htaccess file at `www.domain2.com`, you'll need to proxy the requests back to pinnacle:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory(.*)$ http://store.pinnalcecart.com$1 [L,P]
```

You'll need to make sure mod_proxy is loaded on the domain2.com server. If you need reverse cookie/host rewriting, you can't do this in htaccess and will need to setup the reverse proxy in your vhost config.

This is what you'd need to do to setup a reverse proxy in your vhost config (for domain2.com):

```
ProxyPass /directory/ http://store.pinnalcecart.com/ connectiontimeout=2 retry=10
ProxyPassReverse /directory/ http://store.pinnalcecart.com/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain store.pinnalcecart.com www.domain2.com
```

Take a look at the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) documentation for more connectivity options.

The `ProxyPassReverse` directive rewrites redirects and hosts and the `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` directive rewrites the hostname in cookies. You may or may not need these two.

You need to ensure mod_proxy is loaded, in your httpd.conf file you should have a line like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

(uncommented)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you explain how to load mod_proxy and how to setup reverse proxy? Really appreciate your time!

Comment: All the mod_proxy and proxypass stuff would be done on the domain where I want the URLs to read? so not the Pinnacle cart but the domain.com/sub correct?

Comment: @whoback yes, for `domain2.com`